# How do I copy and paste text from Windows 8 Kindle app book to Microsoft Word

Tags: kindle, windows

I need to open up my Windows 8 Kindle app and while reading a book, I want to cut and paste certain passages to a Word document. I did this before a while back but can't seem to do it again (or remember how I did it before). I used the dual screen that Windows 8 allows and then highlighted the passages and somehow copy and pasted them into the Word document. I think I used the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> to paste, but that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You [can't do it directly from the desktop reader app for Windows 8](http://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/1276426-kindle-app-copy-paste-issue).

You can, however, do one of the following things instead:

## 1. Use Kindle Cloud Reader

- Highlight the text you want to copy.
- Go to https://kindle.amazon.com/your_highlights and find the highlight in question.
- Copy and paste the text from there.

Of course, use this within the limits of copyright, etc.

[See this related question about essentially the same thing](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/13/extracting-notes-and-highlighting-from-kindle-books).

## 2. Use the Windows 7 app

If you can stand the non-Metro layout, you can run the Windows 7 app on Windows 8 ([see this discussion](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/a/972/38).  The Windows 7 app allows copying: when you highlight text and right click, "Copy" is one of the options:

[image]

Comment: On version 1.10.8 you can't copy anymore. "Copy" has been replaced by "Search".

Answer (score 0):

It is a crap solution but if you select and search you can then copy from the search window.

Why Amazon wants to make it that hard I don't know. The old copy function included the reference which was quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

In your Amazon account when you purchase a kindle book,  download it "your PC" I was unable to copy and paste when downloading electronic books to my windows 8,10, to my tablet, but when I selected download to "your PC " it worked without a problem.  The kindle for PC app has a bluish background,  thats that app I use,  the kindle app with the black background would not allow me to copy and paste, but the kindle for PC app does